# How to draw Tissot's ellipse (Tissot's indicatrix) in Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, openlayers, ellipse

[OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/) supports [tissot's ellipses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tissot's_indicatrix) natively [by adding a sphere to the circular() method](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.10.1/examples/tissot.html).

Unfortunately the [Leaflet L.circle()](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#circle) does not support such feature.

How do I draw tissot's ellipses with Leaflet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT 3:

New proposition using [leaflet-geodesy](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-geodesy) which seems a perfect fit for your need. It is exempt from Turf's bug (see Edit 2 below).

The API is quite simple:

```js
LGeo.circle([51.441767, 5.470247], 500000).addTo(map);
```

(center position in [latitude, longitude] degrees, radius in meters)

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ve2huzxw/61/

Quick comparison with nathansnider's solution: http://fiddle.jshell.net/58ud0ttk/2/

(shows that both codes produce the same resulting area, the only difference being in the number of segments used for approximating the area)

EDIT: a nice page that compares Leaflet-geodesy with the standard L.Circle: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/leaflet-geodesy/

---

EDIT 2:

Unfortunately Turf uses [JSTS Topology Suite](https://github.com/bjornharrtell/jsts) to build the buffer. It looks like this operation in JSTS does not fit a non-plane geometry like the Earth surface.

The bug is reported [here](https://github.com/Turfjs/turf-buffer/issues/7) and as of today the main Turf library does not have a full workaround.

So **the below answer (edit 1) produces WRONG results**.

See [nathansnider's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33909803/5108796) for a workaround for building a buffer around a point.

---

EDIT 1:

You can easily build the described polygon by using [Turf](http://turfjs.org/). It offers the `turf.buffer` method which creates a polygon with a specified distance around a given feature (could be a simple point).

So you can simply do for example:

```js
var pt = {
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {},
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [5.470247, 51.441767]
  }
};

var buffered = turf.buffer(pt, 500, 'kilometers');

L.geoJson(pt).addTo(map);
L.geoJson(buffered).addTo(map);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ve2huzxw/41/

---

Original answer:

Unfortunately it seems that there is currently no Leaflet plugin to do so.

It is also unclear what the Tissot indicatrix should represent:

1. A true ellipse that represents the deformation of an infinitely small circle (i.e. distortion at a single point), or
2. A circular-like shape that represents the deformation of a finite-size circle when on the Earth surface, like the OpenLayers demo you link to?

In that demo, the shape in EPSG:4326 is not an ellipse, the length in the vertical axis decreases at higher latitude compared to the other half of the shape.

If you are looking for that 2nd option, then you would have to manually build a polygon that represents the intersection of a sphere and of the Earth surface. If my understanding is correct, this is what the OL demo does. If that is an option for you, maybe you can generate your polygons there and import them as GeoJSON features into Leaflet? :-)

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.
For my project I'm looking for the representation number 2:
I'm placing markers on a map from a geo-based search. The search itself has a position (e.g. the current location of your cell phone). To represent the searched area, the marker with the longest distance to the center is being taken. It's easy to draw a circle with the given distance, but this is a wrong representation. So, I have to create a polygon where all points have the identical distance (in meters, not pixels) to the search center. Unfortunately I do not find a proper way to create this polygon.

Comment: Yep that is the difficult part definitely. You could have a look at how OL handles it.

Comment: You may already have found a solution since then, but just in case, it turns out it is easily do-able with Turf.js. I will edit the above answer.

Comment: This is really great. Thank you for this solution.

Comment: @ghybs, I think turf.buffer may have a bug that affects buffers in real units like km. See this, for example: http://jsfiddle.net/nathansnider/LLb7ffqs/ (click on the axes to see distances in degrees and km). It looks like turf.buffer uses the distance in km to get a distance in degrees, then just calculates the buffer using degrees rather than km. While the N-S dimension of the buffer appears to be correct, the real (in km) E-W dimension gets narrower as latitude increases. This makes some sense, as the Tissot ellipses for a Mercator projection should be closer to circles than they are here.

Comment: Very good catch! the resulting shape looked weird with my code indeed, I should not have trusted Turf… It seems to me that the "bug" is in Turf since the beginning? Is it also true for JSTS? OpenLayers probably uses something else for the sphere computation. Something has to be done to correct Turf!

Answer (score 1):

Because turf.buffer appears to have a bug at the moment, here is a different approach with turf.js, this time using [turf.destination](http://turfjs.org/static/docs/module-turf_destination.html) rotated over a range of bearings to create a true circle:

```
//creates a true circle from a center point using turf.destination
//arguments are the same as in turf.destination, except using number of steps 
//around the circle instead of fixed bearing. Returns a GeoJSON Polygon as output.

function tissotish(center, radius, steps, units) {
    var step_angle = 360/steps;
    var bearing = -180;
    var tissot = { "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [[]]
    };
    for (var i = 0; i < steps + 1; ++i) {
        var target =  turf.destination(center, radius, bearing, units);
        var coords = target.geometry.coordinates;
        tissot.coordinates[0].push(coords);
        bearing = bearing + step_angle;
    }
    return tissot;
}
```

This doesn't produce a true Tissot's indicatrix (which is supposed to measure distortion at a single point), but it does produce a true circle, which from your other comments seems to be what you're looking for anyway. Here it is at work in an example fiddle:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/nathansnider/58ud0ttk/

For comparison, I added the same measurement lines here as I applied to [ghybs's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33538895/5403120) above. (When you click on the lines, they do say that the horizontal distance is greater than 500km at higher latitudes, but that is because, the way I created them, they end up extending slightly outside the circle, and I was too lazy to crop them.)