# Anything in Leaflet that is similar to isLocationOnEdge() from Google Maps?

Tags: leaflet, geo

Google Maps has the function `isLocationOnEdge(point, polyline, tolerance)` that takes a tolerance value in degrees and uses it to determine whether a point falls near a polyline.

Is there anything similar in Leaflet(or some plug-in) that does the same thing?

Answer (score 4):

A handful library for such operation is [Turf](http://turfjs.org/).

For your case, a simple approach would be to:

1. Create a polygon out of your polyline using [`turf.buffer`](http://turfjs.org/docs/#buffer) with appropriate "tolerance" (Turf takes a distance at Earth surface, or degrees).
2. Check whether your point is within that polygon or not using [`turf.inside`](http://turfjs.org/docs/#inside).

Unfortunately, `turf.buffer` is only an [approximation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33526678/how-to-draw-tissots-ellipse-tissots-indicatrix-in-leaflet/33538895#33538895), it does not takes geodesy into account… therefore for big tolerance you will have a deformed shape.

An exact method could be to:

1. Use instead [`turf.pointOnLine`](http://turfjs.org/docs/#pointonline) to find the nearest point of the polyline.
2. [`turf.distance`](http://turfjs.org/docs/#distance) to measure the distance between those 2 points, and compare with your tolerance (or even just Leaflet [`latLng.distanceTo`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#latlng-distanceto), but you would have to convert GeoJSON points back to Leaflet LatLngs).